# Custom View InflateException For Drawing Application in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to code a touchscreen interactive drawing application inside android studios with a fragment; however, I am receiving an error of but fails to find what it is caused by and how to fix it. I am a beginner to app development and simply was following a tutorial. See the link below and please notify me if you need additional information. Thank you so much in advance!

I suspect it is caused by the package name in the xml file or the constructors in the java file!

Problems/Errors

> at
>   com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning.MatchPlanning.onCreateView(MatchPlanning.java:67)
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning/com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error
>   inflating class com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView

Java Class

```
package com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
* Created by AlexKer on 16-02-06.
*/
public class SimpleDrawingView extends View {
//set up initial paint color
private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
//defines paint and canvas
private Paint drawPaint;
//path
private Path path = new Path();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
}

public SimpleDrawingView(Context context){
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}

public SimpleDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    /*setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();*/
}

private void setupPaint() {
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

// Get x and y and append them to the path
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Starts a new line in the path
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Draws line between last point and this point
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    postInvalidate(); // Indicate view should be redrawn
    return true; // Indicate we've consumed the touch
}
}
```

Below is the onCreateView

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_match_planning, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

And XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_match_plan"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center|top"
tools:context="com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning.MatchPlanning"
android:background="@drawable/field">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/SimpleDrawingView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the package name is also wrong in XML. Should be
com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning.

I have no idea what the view is you're trying to use, but this seems super unusual:

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Try this:

```
<com.app2016.alexker.matchplanning.SimpleDrawingView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SimpleDrawingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also -- currently, the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout is useless.

Comment: The application successfully launched, thank you, but whenever I try to draw with the paint brush it crashes and displays "unfortunately MatchPlanning has stopped". Do you know what might have caused that? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a separate question. You should open a new thread. The problem is this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.graphics.Paint.mNativePaint' on a null object reference

Comment: It would probably run if you uncomment this: setupPaint(); in your second constructor.

Comment: Yes I got it, I have one last question: is two separate constructors necessary, or can I just use the second one with both context and attribute?Thank you!

Comment: You need the second constructor. It's used to pass attributes from XML (the second param). Hold control or command and click through super() in either constructor and read the documentation.